# Usage of `deferred_segment_creation`

Tags: oracle11g

Heard that `deferred_segment_creation` had been introduced since `Oracle 11g`. I have gone through the documentation. Do we need to set the value of `deferred_segment_creation` for each table we created? Someone please help me in understanding the usage of `deferred_segment_creation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Deferred_segment_creation`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams075.htm#REFRN10307) is normally set at the database level though it can be set at a session level.  You can specify `segment creation deferred` when you create the table but that is very rare.

Generally `deferred_segment_creation` is helpful when you are installing large packaged applications that create thousands of tables of which many if not most will never be use in a particular installation.  That avoids wasting space for tables that will never have any data.  If you're building an application, you're probably not creating a ton of tables that will never have data so this is much  less useful.